# Como exportar e importar um banco de dados

Tags: mongodb

Eu tenho o mongodb instalado em dois computadores diferentes, onde eu estou estudando/desenvolvendo aplicativos. Normalmente ao final do dia, eu mando todo o código para um servidor Git, mas o banco de dados permanece local.

> Gostaria de saber como levar o banco de dados (inteiro) de um computador para o outro, para que eu possa ter acesso aos mesmos registros que uso para teste - e se existir uma maneira "melhor" de trabalhar, qual seria ela.

*PS. Eu conheço serviços como [mongoDB Atlas](https://www.mongodb.com/) e [mLab](https://mlab.com/) - isso **não** é o que eu procuro.*

Comment: A tua idéia é sincronizar os bancos, deixar eles automagicamente com os mesmos dados? Ou fazer um backup de um computador e levar para o outro é suficiente?

Comment: @JorgeC.BernhardTautz sem automágicas - só *backup* mesmo! ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Opção 1:**

[mongodump](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongodump/) e [mongorestore](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongorestore/#bin.mongorestore). São duas ferramentas que estão no diretório bin da instalação do MongoDB. Você poderia fazer um script para automatizar o dump de um lado, e restore do outro. Existe um artigo (em inglês) sobre o backup com essas ferramentas [aqui](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/backup-and-restore-tools/). O serviço do banco (mongod) precisa estar ativo nas duas máquinas nesse caso.

Exemplo do mongodump:

- Linux: `mongodump -h localhost --gzip -o /Backups/MongoDB/dados`
- Windows: `mongodump /h localhost /gzip /o C:\Backups\MongoDB\dados`

O comando acima faz backup de todos os bancos de dados de um servidor MongoDB executando no computador local, na porta padrão (27017). Compacta esse backup e coloca os dados no diretório /Backups/MongoDB/dados. Existem várias opções do comando, vale olhar a documentação. Um simples `mongodump` já executa o backup de um banco rodando na máquina local, colocando os arquivos em um diretório "dump" dentro do diretório atual.

Exemplos do mongorestore:

- Linux: `mongorestore -h localhost --gzip --dir /Backups/MongoDB/dados`
- Windows: `mongorestore /h localhost /gzip /dir C:\Backups\MongoDB\dados`

O comando restaura em um servidor executando em localhost, descompactando o resultado (--gzip) presente no diretório /Backups/MongoDB/dados. Estou considerando que você usou os exemplos acima para gerar o backup/dump. Se você usar a opção de gerar o backup em um arquivo, por exemplo, deve usar a opção --archive.

**Opção 2**

Copiar os arquivos de dados de uma instalação para outra também é uma opção viável. Inclusive é um dos métodos recomendados como backup na [documentação](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/backups/#back-up-by-copying-underlying-data-files) do MongoDB.

**Não recomendo**

Usar o [mongoexport](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoexport/#bin.mongoexport) e [mongoimport](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoimport/#bin.mongoimport) pois eles trabalham com saída/entrada de arquivos de texto. Assim você perde informações:

- Você está convertendo BSON para JSON, o JSON não tem informações tão ricas quanto aos tipos de dados.
- Os índices que você criou nas collections não são levados no processo. Você precisa recriar eles quando fizer a importação.

Comment: Obrigado! Você pode colocar um exemplo de uso dos dois comandos para quem chegar aqui já saber o que fazer?

Comment: @DanielGomes adicionei os exemplos e dei uma organizada pra ficar claro que são duas opções.